# Is there a smarter way to check if a User liked a Location in my example?

Tags: java, spring

Okay so I have a person entity, which is the user, that looks like this:

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "person_liked_locations",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Location> likedLocations;
}
```

and I have a Location entity that looks like this:

```
public class Location {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @Formula("(select count(*) from person_liked_locations pll where pll.location_id=id)")
    private int likeCount;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "likedLocations")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Person> likedBy;
}
```

Now, in my React app I want to render a like/dislike icon. If the user already likes a location, they can dislike it.

As you can see I have a `@JsonIgnore` on my `likedLocations` field, because if a user has 2000 liked locations, I don't think it would be a great idea to send them all to the user.

I am wondering what would be a good way to implement this feature? Would I need to create a `/api/location/hasliked/{id}` endpoint and create a request for each and every location that I render on the front end to check if the user liked it or not? Also, when the user clicks the like/dislike button, should I fetch the entire location again or should I just invert the state of the like/dislike button on the frontend without checking the database again?

Comment: As a general comment, having your client-facing API be a subset of your persistence model seems like a big code smell.

Comment: "table that looks like this" - no, the _entity_ looks like this. Don't confuse entities with the tables they might be mapped to (note that you could use NoSQL databases which don't have tables)

Comment: Sorry @Michael but I have no idea what that means, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Thomas youre right, i know the difference i just wrote table for some reason without thinking twice

Comment: @randomprogramming Your class which represents the JSON that the UI gets and your class which represents what is stored in the DB is the same thing. Suppose you need to add the field bankAccount to your user ID. If you forget to JsonIgnore it, that is automatically going to be exposed to all clients. Using 2 different models allows you to shape the data into the format that is appropriate for each.

Comment: @Michael so I would have a `BasePerson`, which gets returned to the users, and a `Person` entity which would extend `BasePerson` and never returned to the front end?

Comment: No. Keep them completely separate. No inheritance. Decide what your front-end should look like. Decide what your back-end should look like. Write 1 class for each. You will need some glue code to convert one to the other. It might seem less convenient but you'll be grateful for it later. Don't assume that inheritance is necessary because some of the fields look similar. If they are conceptually distinct, implement them that way.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are rendering the location component.
I suppose you already prepared an endpoint that provides location details.
You can extend this location response with info **boolean isLiked** like **likeCount**.

Comment: In this case I would need to dynamically change the `@Formula` value, based on the person that requested the data... How would that be done?